# Spring integration Scheduled job

Tags: spring, spring-integration, scheduled-tasks

I have written a scheduler in my spring integration application and it is working as expected for success scenarios. i have a question regarding error scenario's and how to handle it. This is the definition of the scheduler -

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="scheduler" method="process" trigger="cronSchedule" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<bean id="cronSchedule" class="org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="data"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.util.TimeZone" ref="timeZone"/>
</bean>
```

What I want to know is there a way to define a error channel for this scheduler like we do in spring chain?

I have a global errorChannel defined in my spring integration and I was hoping to invoke it when there is any error during the execution of this scheduler. Can someone help me with possible configuration to handle this situation?

Answer (score 6):

Consider using a cron poller with an `inbound-channel-adapter` instead of a scheduled task; then you can add an `error-channel` to the poller to handle errors (errors will go to the global error channel by default).

Comment: Hi Gary , in this same scenario I'm running a "MessageGroupStoreReaper" in scheduled task as mentioned on documentation , is there way to catch the error on the global "errorChannel" ?  Please suggest

Comment: In normal aggregation it works fine but in case of timeout its not going on global "errorChannel" , I believe "scheduled task" which is executing the reaper is the culprit.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on 2 year old answers; it doesn't help others find answers. I am not sure what "error" you are talking about. Messages in expired groups can either be sent to the `discardChannel` or aggregated as a partial result. There is no "error" in this case. If this is not clear, ask a new question with much more detail.

Comment: Thanks Gary , I'm taking about a scenario where "send-partial-result-on-expiry" is true but while processing we got some exception in code which is not getting forwarded to the global "errorChannel"

Comment: I can't "guess" what you are talking about with "we got some exception". Ask a new question showing much more detail and explanation of the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Gary , I should have asked a new question for this. I have resolved this using "int:request-handler-advice-chain" to catch the exception. Again many thanks for helping the community on the spring integration issues.